# jQuery + onClick Problem when using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, onclick

I had a line of code just like this:

```
<a onClick="someFunc();">Click</a>
```

It worked fine. But I tried to output it in PHP as such:

```
echo "<h3>" . $zone . " <a href='javascript:$('#zoneNotifUnsub').submit()'>Unsubscribe</a></h3>";
```

And it doesn't work. Using `onClick` or `href` makes no difference, the result is that the code doesn't work. It's clearly some issue of how PHP outputs `<a>` elements. Any help?

Comment: first thing separate the server side code and uI code ,all click handles should be handled at uI level, this is very old way of doing it.

Comment: give a class name to the href and handle the click event in the jquery.., this way it will be very cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with PHP, you've just included a syntax error in the output, see:

```
"<a href='javascript:$('#zoneNotifUnsub').submit()'>"
```

Note the apostraphes?

You'll need to escape them, ie:

```
"<a href='javascript:$(\'#zoneNotifUnsub\').submit()'>"
```

Or

```
 "<a href='javascript:$(\"#zoneNotifUnsub\").submit()'>"
```

Comment: I think `"<a href='javascript:$(\'#zoneNotifUnsub\').submit()'>"` will still generate an error, as the escapes are in the PHP string, not the HTML string. You would have to do: `"<a href='javascript:$(\\'#zoneNotifUnsub\\').submit()'>"`

Answer (score 0):

PHP outputs `a` like any other element - as the HTML serialised in a string, i.e. it doesn't output it any special way.

Since you are using jQuery, your best bet is probably...

```
$('h3 a').click(function() { $('#zoneNotifUnsub').submit(); });
```